# Failover and strong consistency in Couchbase

Tags: nosql, couchbase, failover, consistency, couchbase-java-api

We have a three-node Couchbase cluster with two replicas and durability level MAJORITY.
This means that the mutation will be replicated to the active node(`node A`) and to one of the two replicas(`node B`) before it is acknowledged as successful.

In terms of consistency, what will happen if `node A` becomes unavailable and the hard failover process promotes `node C` replica before `node A` manages to replicate the mutation to `node C`?

According to the docs [Protection Guarantees and Automatic Failover](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/data/durability.html#protection-guarantees-and-automatic-failover), write is durable but will be available immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by @ingenthr [here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/failover-and-strong-consistency-in-couchbase/32849).

> Assuming the order is that the client gets the acknowledgment of the
> durability, then the hard failover is triggered of your node A, during
> the failover the cluster manager and the underlying data service will
> determine whether node B or C should be promoted to active for that
> vbucket (a.k.a. partition) to satisfy all promised durability. That
> was actually one of the trickier bits of implementation.
>
> “Immediately” is pretty much correct. Technically it does take some
> time to do the promotion of the vbucket, but this should be very short
> as it’s just metadata checks and state changes and doesn’t involve any
> data movement. Clients will need to be updated with the new topology
> as well. How long is a function of the environment and what else is
> going on, but I’d expect single-digit-seconds or even under a second.
> Assuming you’re using a modern SDK API 3.x client with best-effort
> retries, it will be mostly transparent to your application, but not
> entirely transparent since you’re doing a hard failover.
> Non-idempotent operations, for example, may bubble up as errors.